# Correct usage of the possessive in the name "Christiaan Huygens"

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I'm writing a lab for a simple diffraction experiment, and I am stuck on this grammatical point:

Is it more appropriate to say "Huygens' Principle" or "Huygens's Principle"*? A cursory glance at Google seems to indicate that the most common usage seems to be "Huygens' Principle"; but as the apostrophe is at the end of the word as in the plural possessive, my inner grammarian is screaming that it should be "Huygens's". Which is correct?

*I know it can also be rendered as the Huygens-Fresnel Principle, obviating the need for my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a degree of ambivalence between Huygens' and Huygens's.  The *Chicago Manual of Style* says that either may be used, whereas Professor Strunk (*The Elements of Style*) [insists it is Huygens's](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html#1).

I personally prefer Huygens's, as it seems to more explicitly indicate the possessive.  Your mileage may differ.

See Wikipedia on [English possessive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Nouns_and_noun_phrases).

Comment: Huygens's Principle sounds fine to me, but some of my colleagues have declared it anathema. I think I will stick with Professor Strunk!

Answer (score 4):

Depends on whom you ask!

Some grammarians say, "If the extra apostrophe s (*'s*) makes the word difficult to say, then drop it and stick with just an apostrophe (').

That makes sense to me, especially with words such as

> - *Moses's* roles as leader, prophet, lawgiver . . ..
> - *Jesus's* words of wisdom . . ..
> - These two *leases's* conditions state specifically that . . ..

Those italicized words would then become

> - *Moses'* roles as leader, prophet, lawgiver . . ..
> - *Jesus'* words of wisdom . . ..
> - These two *leases'* conditions state specifically that . . ..

Some grammarians say that "Rule are rules. Even if a word ends in *s* and the resulting apostrophe (which indicates the possessive) creates a tongue twister, you must still attach the apostrophe *('s)*."

Still other grammarians say, "Who gives a crap? Do watcha gotta do. Just be consistent."

Comment: I like your answer!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist. Thanks! I like yours's too! (Now wait a minute . . ..) Don